# How can I use `sprintf` in PDF::Extract

Tags: perl

I am currently using the [`PDF::Extract`](https://metacpan.org/module/PDF%3a%3aExtract) module

I tried:

```
testing.pdf
```

Script:

```
use strict;

use PDF::Extract;

my $input = $ARGV[0];
my $newpdf = new PDF::Extract(PDFDoc => $input);
my $i = 1;
$i++ while ($newpdf->savePDFExtract(PDFPages => sprintf("%03d", $i)));
```

This script run successfully, but some page missing during the extraction.
2. points:

```
use strict;

use PDF::Extract;

my $input = $ARGV[0];
my $newpdf = new PDF::Extract(PDFDoc => $input);
my $i = 1;
$i++ while ($newpdf->savePDFExtract(PDFPages => $i));
```

This script runs successfully and all pages extract successfully, but I all page extracted and with sequences `001`, `002`, `003` etc.

For example:

```
testing001.pdf
testing002.pdf
testing003.pdf
```

...etc.

All pages also in this form without the missing page. How can I get this?

Comment: I don't understand "all pages also this form without missing page". Could you elaborate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `PDFPages` parameter of `savePDFExtract` takes a list of page numbers.  It isn't designed to let you specify a custom file naming scheme.  You can specify the name yourself instead, something like this:

```
$i++ while ($newpdf->savePDFExtract(
        PDFPages  => $i, 
        PDFSaveAs => $base_file_name . sprintf("%03d", $i)
    )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should always `use warnings`, which isn't as critical as `use strict` but will offer some valuable debugging information on problems that are easy to overlook.

I know it's not what the documentation says, but you should also avoid the indirect object notation as in `new PDF::Extract`. A class method call `PDF::Extract->new` is much safer.

I don't understand why your program is skipping pages as it stands, as the string `001` is just as valid as the numeric value `1`. But the way to specify an output file name is to set the `PDFSaveAs` option for the xcall to the required file name string.

This code works by building a `sprintf` format from the original filename. For example it changes `testing.pdf` to `testing%03.pdf`. This format can then be used in a call to `setVars` to name the file before it is generated.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use PDF::Extract;

my $input = $ARGV[0];
my $format = $input =~ s/\.([^.]*)\z/%03d.$1/r;

my $newpdf = new PDF::Extract(PDFDoc => $input);

my $i = 1;
while (1) {
    $newpdf->setVars(PDFSaveAs => sprintf($format, $i));
    my $success = $newpdf->savePDFExtract(PDFPages => $i));
    last unless $success;
    ++$i;
}
```

Comment: The skipping of pages is probably related to how it processes the extended syntax that the `PDFPages` option allows.  You can enter things like `'1-5 8'`.

Answer (score 0):

This script is overkill for what you are trying to do.  I would just use PDFTK:
http://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-the-pdf-toolkit/

It can accomplish what you need very efficiently:

```
pdftk testing.pdf burst output testing%03d.pdf
```

If you need this to be part of a Perl script, you can call out to PDFTK with a system call.

Comment: pdftk looks like a useful suggestion, but I would hardly call this tiny script "overkill".  And if Perl is needed for other functionality, it is generally better to use a Perl module than to make a system call to an external program.

Comment: You're right, "overkill" was probably too strong!  But if this is the only task the script accomplishes, I would say why reinvent the wheel?